# Not able to access Cassandra server from Android app. Error : java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:9160 - Connection refused

Tags: android, cassandra, thrift, connectexception

My Adnroid app is running on AVD and Cassandra server is running on Windows 7 (same machine) Below is the code snippet I have used for connecting to Cassandra client.

```
TTransport tr = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket("127.0.0.1", 9160));
TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(tr);
Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);
tr.open();
```

I have tried to debug; it creates the socket with isClose() = 'false' (that means socket is open) but further it fails to connect (TSocket.open())

-------------------------Code from org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket--------------------

```
try {
socket_.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host_, port_), timeout_);
inputStream_ = socket_.getInputStream();
outputStream_ = socket_.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException iox) {
close();
throw new TTransportException(TTransportException.NOT_OPEN, iox);
```

### }

It seems to be a problem with cross platform and the Windows OS (as Android apps are on Linux). Is there any better way I can connect to Cassandra server from Android app ?
You help and time is higly appreciated.

Thanks
Randeep

Comment: If you find this answer is correct then please accept as a correct answer, by mark right symbol below voting buttons on left hand side of my answr. (It will help you and other user also..)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what are you doing, (Its solved your problem or not) But one thing is getting clear that Android emulator doesn't understand `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, If you want to connect localhost then either use a `public IP` of system or `10.0.2.2` (for localhost)..

Comment: Hey! 
Thanks alot for the help. It worked for me. I have configured the Cassandra server with my public IP and used the same IP while  connecting through Android app and everything works fine now.

Thanks
Randeep